# Eclipse RCP StatusManager - how to change the title

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am trying to use StatusManager to display and/or log messages. Not necessarily bad and nasty problems, but also info's or warnings. This is what I basically do:

```
Status status= new Status(IStatus.INFO, MainPlugin.ID, "Some info message");
StatusManager.getManager().handle(status, StatusManager.SHOW | StatusManager.LOG);
```

Works well, but I can't find the way to modify the default title of the popup dialog - it always says "Problem Occurred". Going through the maze of eclipse code brought me here to ask this question because I am totally lost... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately setting dialog title is not possible now. The dialog is generated based on `IStatus` object when you give a proper flag (such as `StatusManager.SHOW`), but the interface does not define a title. To allow what you want, the `IStatus` interface should be extended.

The same problem occurs in Eclipse 4 (there is a new `StatusReporter` class).

You can follow the bug [Bug 386023](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386023) which postulates exactly what you want (on Eclipse 4 platform).